# C programming file operations reading the characters from the file and performing arithimitic operations on the numeric characters

Tags: c

I want to write a file enter random characters from the user input and then be able to read the file and take only the numeric characters and perform arithmetic on those numeric characters, however, after i create the file and write to it I am not able to read the file and extract data from it. the user input and output are shown below.

```
Please enter a string, no spaces: 1234567891234hgfns 
the total number of integers is 0
the sum is: 0.00
This is the mean: nan
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

```
  #include <stdio.h>

// defining a function to calculate and output the mean
float mean(float sum, float N)
{
   float mean = sum/N;
    printf("This is the mean: %.2f\n", mean);
    
    return mean;
}


int main(void) {
   
   
     // declaring the variables
    char ch;
    int N = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    
    // creating and opening a file
    FILE *Fptr;
    
    Fptr = fopen("File.txt","w");
    
    
    // prompting the user to input string
    printf("Please enter a string, no spaces: ");
    
    // creating a loop to keep taking in characters until a blank space is detected
    while( ch != ' ')
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        
        // writing to the file
        fprintf(Fptr,"%c", ch);
    }
    
    fopen("File.txt","w");
    //reading from the file and printing only numbers from the characters
    while(fscanf(Fptr, "%c", &ch) != EOF)
    {
        // usign if statements
        if( ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' || ch == '5' ||
           ch == '6' || ch == '7' || ch == '8' || ch == '9')
        {
            printf("%c\n", ch);
            N++;
            sum += (float)ch;

        }
    }
    
    // printing the the total number of integers
    printf("the total number of integers is %d\n", N);
    printf("the sum is: %.2lf\n", sum);
    
    // calling the function mean to calculate the mean
    mean(sum, N);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I am not able" is not a problem description. Why not? What goes wrong? Maybe you should `fclose()` to save before `fopen()`ing to read... and maybe you should try checking the return values of all these, to know whether it's valid to read/write/use pointers/etc.

Comment: And reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ could be very usefull too

Comment: Pranav Tyagi, The first time `while( ch != ' ')` is executed, what is the value of `ch`?

Comment: Why are you using scanf at all?  To read a char, use `fgetc` or `getchar`.  Do not attempt to use `scanf` until you have a lot more experience with the language.  To the beginner (and to the expert) `scanf` is a snake pit full of venom.  Don't touch it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it does not have a value, it takes it from the user input, and this works quite alright as it is able to write to the file.

Comment: Pranav Tyagi "it does not have a value," --> code should not attempt to read until it does. It should be assigned _first.

Comment: To emphasize the point @chux-ReinstateMonica is trying to make: your input loop is wrong.  If the input stream does not contain a space, that will be an infinite loop.  If you are going to use `scanf`, you must *always* check the value that it returns.  You should write your initial loop as `int c; while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != ' ' ) { ...`

Comment: `(float)ch` when `ch == '2'` is not 2.0.  If you are trying to add digits, you need to do something like `sum += ch - '0'`

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is `fopen("File.txt","w");`.  That call will open the file, but it will delete all the data in it.  If you want to read from a file, open it with mode "r".

Comment: the output does not change even after i have removed this. the code seems to execute properly however, seems to be skipping the second while loop containing the if statement which results in a blank output

Comment: Unless you close the handle you opened for writing, no data will have yet been written to the file when you try to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Close the file first and *then* open for reading.

```
Fptr = fopen("File.txt","w");
...
fclose(Fptr);  // add
// fopen("File.txt","w");
Fptr = fopen("File.txt","r");
```

Or research `freopen()`.

Or open for reading and writing `"w+"` and `rewind()` before reading.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues to be addressed in your code.  Rather than trying to explain each, it is easier just to show you alternate ways to solve your problem.  A couple of note worthy points issues should be addressed, however. You do not close the file, so no data gets written until the program terminates.  That means it is not available to be read when you are trying to read it.  You open the file with mode "w"; if there had been any data in the file it would be truncated (discarded) by that.  You discard the value returned by `fopen`, and you cannot use a file handle that you have discarded.  Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <ctype.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
float                                                                              
mean(float sum, float N)                                                           
{                                                                                  
        float mean = sum/N;                                                        
        printf("This is the mean: %.2f\n", mean);                                  
        return mean;                                                               
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
FILE *xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);                                  
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(void)                                                                         
{                                                                                  
        int ch;                                                                    
        int N = 0;                                                                 
        float sum = 0;                                                             
        FILE *Fptr = xfopen("File.txt","w");                                       
        printf("Please enter a string, no spaces: ");                              
                                                                                   
        while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != ' ' ) {                            
                fputc(ch, Fptr);                                                   
        }                                                                          
        fclose(Fptr);                                                              
        Fptr = xfopen("File.txt","r");                                             
        while( (ch = fgetc(Fptr)) != EOF ) {                                       
                if( isdigit(ch) ) {                                                
                        putchar(ch);                                               
                        N++;                                                       
                        sum += ch - '0';                                           
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        printf("the total number of integers is %d\n", N);                         
        printf("the sum is: %.2lf\n", sum);                                        
        mean(sum, N);                                                              
        return 0;                                                                  
} 

FILE *                                                                             
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)                                         
{                                                                                  
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :         
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;                                     
        if( fp == NULL ) {                                                         
                perror(path);                                                      
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return fp;                                                                 
}
```